# Save HttpPostedFileBase as an image in folder

Tags: model-view-controller, httppostedfilebase

I got a drag&drop-function for images in my application:
It seems to save the file as a `HttpPostedFileBase` with this code:

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
{
    bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;

    foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
    }
}
```

My end goal is to store the imagepath in my DB but for now I would be happy if I could just
convert this `HttpPostedFileBase`-file to a jpg and store it in my image folder in my project. Any tips on how to go about this?

EDIT:
This code seems to convert the the HttpPostedFileBase to an image:

```
   public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
{
    bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;

    foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
         var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            var sourceimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
            img = sourceimage;
    }
}
```

I also added a prop to store it in:

```
public Image img { get; set; }
```

EDIT:

```
   public HttpPostedFileBase DropImg { get; set; }
   public Image img { get; set; }

 public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile(string test)
        {
            bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;

            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                DropImg = file;
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var sourceimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
                img = sourceimage;

                var fullPath = "~/Content/images/drops/" + file.FileName;
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fullPath));
            }




            if (isSavedSuccessfully)
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "File saved" });

            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
            }


        }
```

I was hping that this would save my image to the folder drops...Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
var fullPath = "~/UploadedImages/" + file.FileName;
file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fullPath));
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but i cant get it to work, see update in a minute for my code with yours added.